# categorize data by months of year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table which contains of information about the customers and agents. I want to categorize them by month of year .

to clarify: I would like to know how many customers which registered under different agents in month of a year , same as the below figure :

[image]

---

Comment: `Cross-tab` or `PIVOT` - pick your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT AGENT_CODE, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
FROM 
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, AGENT_CODE, MONTH(DATE) as m
FROM Test) t
PIVOT
(
COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID)
FOR m IN
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvt;
```

returns

```
AGENT_CODE  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
100         1   0   0   0   2   1   1   0   1   0   0   3
101         0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
102         0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
103         0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

add column aliases to get `JAN`, `FEB`, etc. instead of numbers as columns titles.

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/673cb/7

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM (

SELECT year(DATE) as [year],left(datename(month,DATE),3)as [month], AGENT_CODE as cnt FROM yourTable

) as s
PIVOT
(
    count(AGENT_CODE)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot